# EFCore Duplicates in self referencing object

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5

Hi I have a self referencing object which is effectively a reflection of the task > subtask model in project plans where there can be many layers of tasks in a project plan:

```
  public class ProjectPlanItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Guid Reference { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime BaselineStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime BaselineEndDate { get; set; }
        public int Duration { get; set; }
        public string DurationUnit { get; set; }
        public int Progress { get; set; }
        public string Predecessor { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ProjectPlanItem> ProjectPlanSubItems { get; set; } = new  List<ProjectPlanItem>();
    }
```

The DBContext creates the database table correctly by having a FK for the nested `ProjectPlanItemID`

I have the following code in the get method of my controller to do some eager loading:

```
var plans = await _context.ProjectPlans
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanEvents)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanHolidays)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanResources)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanItems)
        .ThenInclude(pi => pi.ProjectPlanSubItems)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This helpfully inflates my object broadly as desired for all off teh associated `ICollection`s apart from the nested project plan items where the nested items appear (incorrectly) at the root and (correctly) within the nested collection. As per the below:

- Group 1

  - Group 1 Sub Item 1
  - Group 1 Sub Item 2
- Group 1 Sub Item 1
- Group 1 Sub Item 2
- Group 2

  - Group 2 Sub Item 1
  - Group 2 Sub Item 2
- Group 2 Sub Item 1
- Group 2 Sub Item 2

Just tried with a further third level of nesting and the same situation repeats but this time

- G1

  - G1 I1
  - G2

    - G2 I1
- G1 I1
- G2

  - G2 I1

I have looked around at lots of 'issue with efcore self referencing' posts here and elsewhere but none mirror this issue (or I am not articulating my search terms well enough).

I have just migrated the project to .net 5 rc2 from .net core 3 in case there was anything useful in the new release

Any thoughts?

UPDATE: Request for the `ProjectPlan` model:

```
public class ProjectPlan
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Guid Reference { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public DateTime VersionDate { get; set; }
        public ProjectPlanStatus Status { get; set; }
        public string WorkWeek { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ProjectPlanItem> ProjectPlanItems { get; set; } = new List<ProjectPlanItem>();
        public ICollection<ProjectPlanEventMarker> ProjectPlanEvents { get; set; } = new List<ProjectPlanEventMarker>();
        public ICollection<ProjectPlanResource> ProjectPlanResources { get; set; } = new List<ProjectPlanResource>();
        public ICollection<ProjectPlanHoliday> ProjectPlanHolidays { get; set; } = new List<ProjectPlanHoliday>();

    }
```

UPDATE 2 - Request for the output with test data (i have not filled the other collections on the parent ProjectPlan item just the ProjectPlanItems it has in a collection).

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "reference": "1735cc99-81d4-42aa-b5f5-62c012e1cd6a",
  "name": "My Project Plan",
  "version": "1.0",
  "versionDate": "2020-10-26T00:00:00",
  "status": 1,
  "workWeek": "Monday",
  "projectPlanItems": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Group 1",
      "reference": "69e9fe1e-8219-4178-b465-6074cd1e08e4",
      "startDate": "2020-10-01T00:00:00",
      "endDate": "2020-10-30T00:00:00",
      "baselineStartDate": "2020-10-01T00:00:00",
      "baselineEndDate": "2020-10-30T00:00:00",
      "duration": 30,
      "durationUnit": "d",
      "progress": 75,
      "predecessor": null,
      "isSubItem": false,
      "projectPlanSubItems": [
        {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "Group 1 Item 1",
          "reference": "f038d10f-862a-468d-b664-d4e848b73cac",
          "startDate": "2020-10-01T00:00:00",
          "endDate": "2020-10-15T00:00:00",
          "baselineStartDate": "2020-10-01T00:00:00",
          "baselineEndDate": "2020-10-15T00:00:00",
          "duration": 15,
          "durationUnit": "d",
          "progress": 75,
          "predecessor": null,
          "isSubItem": true,
          "projectPlanSubItems": []
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Group 1 Item 2",
          "reference": "3d32845b-3a9e-42bf-8a38-414d8822a8c5",
          "startDate": "2020-10-16T00:00:00",
          "endDate": "2020-10-30T00:00:00",
          "baselineStartDate": "2020-10-16T00:00:00",
          "baselineEndDate": "2020-10-30T00:00:00",
          "duration": 15,
          "durationUnit": "d",
          "progress": 75,
          "predecessor": null,
          "isSubItem": true,
          "projectPlanSubItems": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Group 1 Item 1",
      "reference": "f038d10f-862a-468d-b664-d4e848b73cac",
      "startDate": "2020-10-01T00:00:00",
      "endDate": "2020-10-15T00:00:00",
      "baselineStartDate": "2020-10-01T00:00:00",
      "baselineEndDate": "2020-10-15T00:00:00",
      "duration": 15,
      "durationUnit": "d",
      "progress": 75,
      "predecessor": null,
      "isSubItem": true,
      "projectPlanSubItems": []
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Group 1 Item 2",
      "reference": "3d32845b-3a9e-42bf-8a38-414d8822a8c5",
      "startDate": "2020-10-16T00:00:00",
      "endDate": "2020-10-30T00:00:00",
      "baselineStartDate": "2020-10-16T00:00:00",
      "baselineEndDate": "2020-10-30T00:00:00",
      "duration": 15,
      "durationUnit": "d",
      "progress": 75,
      "predecessor": null,
      "isSubItem": true,
      "projectPlanSubItems": []
    }
  ],
  "projectPlanEvents": [],
  "projectPlanResources": [],
  "projectPlanHolidays": []
}
```

You can see in the JSON ProjectPlanItem ID=2 and ID=3 are correctly nested in the collection on ProjectPlanItem ID=1.

They are then repeated in the collection on the Parent root collection incorrectly.

UPDATE 4 - Separate out loading the ProjectPlanItems from the .Include on the parent Project Plan:

I've been playing around and decided to lazy load all of the other colections on the parent ProjectPlan object and then separately load the ProjectPlanItems as a separate step with a .Where selecting only the top level ProjectPlanItems.

```
var projectPlan = await _context.ProjectPlans
    .Where(p=> p.ID==id)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanEvents)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanHolidays)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanResources)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var projectplanitems = await _context.ProjectPlanItems
    .Where(ppi => ppi.IsSubItem == false)
    .Include(ppi => ppi.ProjectPlanSubItems)
    .ToListAsync();

projectPlan.ProjectPlanItems = projectplanitems;
```

This worked and only gave me one item in ProjectPlan.ProjectPLanItems (with ID=1) as anticipated and then 2 items in the ProjectPlanItem.ProjectPlanSubItems with ID of 2 and 3 again as expected.

so then, given I have upgraded the solution to .net5 RC2, I tried to add a .Where in the original lazy loading to (in theory) give me the same query as above but just in the single round trip:

```
var plans = await _context.ProjectPlans
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanEvents)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanHolidays)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanResources)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanItems.Where(p => p.IsSubItem==false))
        .ThenInclude(pi => pi.ProjectPlanSubItems)
    .ToListAsync();
```

But that has no effect and still gives the incorrect output.

Does EF care if I make two queries to fill an object in controller

I assume if I make changes in the client and then post it back EF wouldn't know or care in the slightest?

Comment: Can you share with us your ProjectPlans model?

Comment: @DavidEdel updated the initial question.

Comment: Can you show us the current result and your expected result with some example data?

Comment: @mj1313 Have added the JSON output of the Get method on the API any thoughts would be very welcome.

Comment: FYI - I have got the code to work but have had to make two trips one for the parent ProjectPlan and one for the ProjectPlanItems. Seems unnecessary effort but thoughts as to whether I should just take the hit on that.

Answer (score 0):

For such massive Include query better to use introduced in EF Core 5 `AsSplitQuery()` and pray that it works. Otherwise prepare runnable sample and post bug to EF Core's GitHub site.

```
var plans = await _context.ProjectPlans
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanEvents)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanHolidays)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanResources)
    .Include(p => p.ProjectPlanItems)
        .ThenInclude(pi => pi.ProjectPlanSubItems)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks I have tried adding that to the include query and unfortunately it is the same.